# Complex count query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a json that have the following structure:

```
{"data": {
     "key1": "value1",
     "key2": "value2",
     "manualTests": [{"name": "component1", "passed": false, "x": 12}, 
                     {"name": "component2", "passed": true}, 
                     {"name": "component3", "passed": false, "responseTime": 5}],
     "automaticTests": [{"name": "component4", "passed": false}, 
                        {"name": "component5", "passed": true, "conversion": "Z"}, 
                        {"name": "component6", "passed": false}],
     "semiautomaticTests": [{"name": "component7", "passed": true}, 
                            {"name": "component8", "passed": true}, 
                            {"name": "component9", "passed": true}]
}}
```

My mongoDB contains a really huge number of these and I need to get a list of all the components that have not passed the tests. So the output desired should be:

```
{
    "component1": 150,
    "component2": 35,
    "component3": 17,
    "component4": 5,
    "component5": 3,
    "component6": 1
}
```

The numbers are random and for each component they show how many components did pass the tests. How do I calculate it in mongoDB? The format is not strict, the prime requirement is that the output should contain a name of a component failed and their number out of the whole sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage to consider only tests where there is at-least one fail component.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to extract all the failed components followed by [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to merge all failed components across all tests.

[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to flatten the array and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to count for each failed component.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$match":{
    "$or":[
      {"manualTests.passed":false},
      {"automaticTests.passed":false},
      {"semiautomaticTests.passed":false}
    ]
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "tests":{
      "$concatArrays":[
        {"$filter":{"input":"$manualTests","as":"mt","cond":{"$eq":["$$mt.passed",false]}}},
        {"$filter":{"input":"$automaticTests","as":"at","cond":{"$eq":["$$at.passed",false]}}},
        {"$filter":{"input":"$semiautomaticTests","as":"st","cond":{"$eq":["$$st.passed",false]}}}
      ]
    }
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$tests"},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$tests.name","count":{"$sum":1}}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer! Seems like a pretty complicated query to me. I knew it was not simple...By the way, as far as I understand, you seem to have forgotten specify `data` in front of `manualTests`, `automaticTests` and `semiautomaticTests` cos it's the root element for the json. Cos the first time I tried it it returned nothing , then I added "data" to the appropriate place and it worked like charm. Thank you!